# Spring Validation Ignore Rules

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-boot-starter

i have validation in endpoint

```
@PutMapping("/rename/{id}")
public void renameCategoryByName(@PathVariable long id, @RequestParam @Size(min = 2, max = 20) @Valid String new_name) {
    categoryService.renameCategoryById(id, new_name);
}
```

end when i ping this end point by curl -X PUT -F "new_name=t" http://localhost:8080/category/rename/26, i don't get error and method change the name of entity.

I use this dependency to validation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `@Size(min = 2, max = 20)`. 26 matches that, since it's a string of length (size) 2.

Comment: Did you check any tutorial like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation?

Comment: Please paste your whole dependencies

Comment: RobSpoor im not validate id, just new_name, btw i fix it, i miss @Validated annotation on class